# Files overwritten during cp loop

Tags: unix

I'm trying to copy 4 files that are present in Folder A (main folder) into all subfolders (1000) present in Folder A. To do this I used:

```
for i in *;     
do       
cp  File1.bash $i      
cp  File2.sh $i         
cp  File3.R $i        
cp  File4.R $i       
done
```

Unfortunately, the content of all the files after the cp is overwritten in destination directories. In other words files: File2.sh, File3.R and File4.R  have the content of File1.bash.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the wildcard `*` is replaced by every file in the directory, including File2.sh,, File3.R and so on. So, at one point during the loop, $i will be 'File2.sh,' and you will execute the command `cp File1.bash File2.sh`, which will overwrite File2.sh (the same problem happens for the other files).

You should replace the wildcard with a command which only list directory such as `ls -d */`.

For instance :

```
for i in $(ls -d */)
do
    cp  File1.bash $i      
    cp  File2.sh $i         
    cp  File3.R $i        
    cp  File4.R $i 
done
```

Also , note that cp can take multiple arguments as source, so `cp File1.bash File2.sh File3.R File4.R $i` should do what you want. It is also less error prone as the last parameter is expected to be a directory, so cp will give an error if $i is a regular file.

Comment: You're welcome. Also see my edit about cp taking several arguments and pabouk's answer which contains very useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

The for cycle goes through all files and directories (except ones which name starts with a dot) in the current directory including the files `File1.bash`, `File2.s`, `File3.R`, `File4.R` so sooner or later they will appear in the destination of the `cp` commands and get overwritten.

There are multiple ways how to resolve the problem:

### Expand just directories

```
for i in */ ; do
    cp  File1.bash File2.sh File3.R File4.R "$i"
done
```

### Test if the destination is a directory

```
for i in * ; do
    if test -d "$i" ; then
        cp  File1.bash File2.sh File3.R File4.R "$i"
    fi
done
```

Compared to the first answer this code does not need to call an additional external command (`ls`) and it is not a good idea to parse output of `ls` anyway :) (It could contain some unexpected content.)

### Move the source files to a different place

For example move the files to directory called `.template` (the dot is important) or to a directory outside the current directory (`../template`):

```
mv File1.bash File2.sh File3.R  File4.R .template
```

Changed script (will not cycle through the hidden `.template`):

```
source=.template
for i in * ; do
    cp  "$source/File1.bash" "$i"
    cp  "$source/File2.sh" "$i"
    cp  "$source/File3.R" "$i"
    cp  "$source/File4.R" "$i"
done
```

### Using double quotes

It is a good idea to enclose string where you expand variables between double quotes. Then the script will correctly work with string containing spaces newlines etc. too.

Comment: Haha, originally I forgot the most straightforward solution - the first script :)